# SlimDX - Set state block

Tags: c#, .net, directx, device, slimdx

I want to set states in SlimDX Direct3d9 device.

I have that code at the beging of frameRender function.

```
        device.BeginStateBlock();
        device.SetRenderState(RenderState.ZEnable, false);
        device.SetRenderState(RenderState.Lighting, false);
        device.SetRenderState(RenderState.CullMode, Cull.None);            
        device.EndStateBlock();
```

But I'm getting this error in debug window:

```
Object of type SlimDX.Direct3D9.StateBlock was not disposed. Stack trace of object creation:
```

I'm getting millions of those lines. All of them say the same thing.
How should I dispose those states? How to make it in proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only hint i can give you, given your information, is that EndStackeBlock should return a StateBlock object, which is disposable. My guess is, you get these after a LostDevice event? Before you reset the device you need to free all those resources. 
And of course, the whole reason to make StateBlocks is so that you create them once and reuse them, but it seems you are recreating them everytime and never applying them. So after a while you created a lot of stateblocks without using or disposing any of them.
But maybe you can post more code or give more informations.

Comment: So how should I use them? where to createthem and how to apply them? Shoud I apply them every frame? Should I dispose them every frame?

Comment: I have to say that i'm not an expert in that area, so i can more or less only guess. I would create a stateblock in the beginning of your application, one for each unique stateblock you need. Then you can use the Apply method to use the block, draw everything that needs to be drawn with that block. Remember that directx is a state maschine once set it stays set unless unset or something else is set. Disposing on the otherhand should be done when you lost the device and you want to reset or when you shutdown the application. Unfortunately this is all i can say and i would try it that way.